# Cannot get cookies in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, cookies

I'm trying to obtain I cookie I set from JavaScript code in Android.

I've successfully checked that the web page when loaded by Chrome successfully get a cookie created, so I think it should also happen on the webview.

This is my current code:

```
 webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/www/first_leaflet_webviewer.html");

[…]

String value = getCookie("http://10.0.2.2:8080", "latlng");
```

getCookie is defined as:

```
public String getCookie(String siteName,String CookieName){
        String CookieValue = null;

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);
        if(cookies != null){
            String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
            for (String ar1 : temp ){
                if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){
                    String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
                    CookieValue = temp1[1];
                }
            }
        }
        return CookieValue;
    }
```

But getCookie always returns null as if the cookie were never created.

I've tried to change http://10.0.2.2:8080 for http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/www/first_leaflet_webviewer.html and http://localhost, just in case, but to no avail.

What would I need to change so I'm able to read the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set WebViewClient like this. 
 (note that the snippet is kotlin.)

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                    if (CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url) != null && CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url).contains("latlng")) {
                        //todo
                    }
                }

                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                     if (CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url) != null && CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url).contains("latlng")) {
                        //todo
                    }
                }
 }

webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/www/first_leaflet_webviewer.html")
```